# Should you use the outcome and time to event variable in the predictor matrix?

Tags: r, r-mice, lasso-regression

My question is probably very simple but I still want to see what you think.

I would like to perform LASSO regression with several clinical covariates. Unfortunately, I have a lot of missing values. I`m fairly new to mice which is why I was wondering:

Should I include my outcome and the time-to-outcome variable in my predictor matrix for multiple imputation of these clinical variables?

I have a feeling that this is flawed by introducing bias to the model but maybe I am wrong.